# Pear mail works on localhost using xampp but not on the server

Tags: php, pear-mail

I have a contact page and a page which form data from contact page is posted to
the problem is i can send email using pear mail from localhost using XAMPP but it doesn't work on my server when i upload the files.there's nothing wrong with my server's outgoing smtp while i can send messages using outlook.Thanks for your help if anyone knows what the problem really is !
here is the page which data is posted to :

```
<?php
include_once('Mail.php');
include_once ('securimage/securimage.php');
$securimage = new Securimage();
if ($securimage->check($_POST['captcha_code']) == false) {
  echo "<p>The captcha code you entered is wrong<br/></p>";
  exit;
}
$clientip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$name=$_POST['txtname'];
$family=$_POST['txtfamily'];
$email=$_POST['txtemail'];
$message=$_POST['txtmessage'];
$to = 'nowrouziehsan@gmail.com';
$from=$email;
$subject = 'Sent from my website';
$body ="Name : ".$name."\n"."Family : ".$family."\n"."Email : ".$email."\n".
"Client IP Address : ".$clientip."\n"."Message :\n".$message;
$headers = array(
'From' => $from,
'To' => $to,
'Subject' => $subject
);

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
    'host' => 'mail.alijamshidi.org',
    'port' => '25',//it works fine on the port 587 as well...
    'auth' => true,
    'username' => 'info@alijamshidi.org',
    'password' => 'mypassword'
));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
echo('<p>' . $mail->getMessage().'</p>');
} else {
echo('<p>You have successfully sent the message , stay in tune while we reply you
back</p>');
}
?>
```

Comment: What does PEAR::isError($mail) return?

Comment: It returns nothing...

Comment: use try and catch around the $smtp = block of code and also the $mail = block and see what you get. Also, add turn on error reporting by adding this code after the opening <?php:

ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

Comment: wow,i got so many error messages thanks for your help , this can be very helpful to get it done, here are the errors :

Comment: Strict Standards: Non-static method Mail::factory() should not be called statically in /home/alijamsh/public_html/contactresult.php on line 32

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::raiseError() should not be called statically in /home/alijamsh/public_html/Mail.php on line 83

Fatal error: Call to undefined method PEAR_Error::send() in /home/alijamsh/public_html/contactresult.php on line 34

Comment: Line 83 is probably the deal killer

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think i don't have pear installed on my hosting server.